# log4j how to disable internal messages?

Tags: log4j

I'm using log4j (via slf4j) configured with log4j.xml. I would like to know how can I disable the messages that log4j displays about itself.
For example, if the log file specified in the log4j.xml can't be created, log4j shows the following messages on the console:

> ```
> log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: \LogFile.log (Accesso negato)
>   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
>   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
>   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:136)
>   at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
>   at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
>   at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
>   at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
>   at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:295)
>   at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
>   at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
>   at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
>   at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
>   at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1006)
>   at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:872)
>   at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:778)
>   at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
>   at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
>   at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
>   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
>   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
> ```

I don't want that the users see the full exception stack.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be writing a `com.myapp.SilentErrorHandler` which implements `org.apache.log4j.spi.ErrorHandler` but does nothing.

Configuration in `log4j.xml` would be :

```
 <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
   <errorHandler class="com.myapp.SilentErrorHandler" />
   <param name="File" value="\LogFile.log"/>
   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   ...
   </layout>
 </appender>
```

Note that silently ignoring errors is generally a bad thing. You may consider using `FallbackErrorHandler` which allows to specify a fallback appender if the primary appender fails.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! Also thanks for the suggestion, I'll try FallbackErrorHandler soon. ;)